# Linking to another page within a page’s tab

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have one company, multiple brands. Each brand has it’s own fan page. I would like to have it so when you open up a ‘brands’ tab on one page, there will be links to the other brands Facebook pages.

I have created the ‘brands’ tab itself, but when I open it, there is nothing there except “Go to Facebook.com”

Just looking as to where I can upload the links so they will appear and the user can be linked to the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good idea to create a fanpage tab, but you should use links with _blank or _top target because tab content is displayed inside . Protip - you can even add a like button to each page inside tab.